# C# regex check string contains html

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using following regex pattern to check a string contains html.

```
string input = "<a href=\"www.google.com\">test</a>";
const string pattern = "</?\\w+((\\s+\\w+(\\s*=\\s*(?:\".*?\"|'.*?'|[^'\">\\s]+))?)+\\s*|\\s*)/?>";
Regex reg = new Regex(pattern);
var matches = reg.Matches(input);
```

It works fine but if string text value contains < or > characters it returns true too, but it shouldn't.
For example the following is not considered an HTML tag in our system.

```
string input = "<test>";
```

How can I add to this pattern an AND for `</` and `/>`

Thanks

Comment: why don't you just use the `string.Contains()` method provided to you within C# why make things harder trying to figure out your RegEx when you could have gotten your results with a single line check.. just curious..

Comment: I believe http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/603384 is relevant here.

Answer (score 3):

I would not use regex to parse or validate HTML. You could use [`HtmlAgilityPack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/):

```
string input = "<a href=\"www.google.com\">test</a>";

var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(input);
bool isValidHtml = doc.ParseErrors.Count() == 0;  // true
```

If you want to allow only specific tags you could create a white-list of allowed tags:

```
var whiteList = new List<string> { "a", "b", "img", "#text" }; //fill more whitelist tags
bool isValidHtmlAndTags = doc.ParseErrors.Count() == 0 && doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
    .All(node => whiteList.Contains(node.Name));
```

Comment: it is a very big project, I cannot add a library or component by myself, so I need to do it with regex.